# Why does hydraqs exploit put "abc" in its x1 array?

Tags: exploit, heapspray, use-after-free

[Here](https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/trojanhydraq-incident-analysis-aurora-0-day-exploit) there is a thorough description of the exploit I am talking about. There is this step:

```
var x1 = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    x1[i] = document.createElement("COMMENT");
    x1[i].data="abc";
};
var e1 = null;
```

where they fill `x1` with the string `"abc"`. Inside the post, they stated, that they would explain later, why this is necessary. But apparently, they forgot it.
In one of the last code sections they state:

> And guess what, the system will reuse the memory that was allocated for the IMG object, which is now free for everyone. This means that the attacker has overwritten the IMG object with the data he wants.

Related Code Section:

```
function ev2() {
    p = "\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d\u0c0d";
    for (i = 0; i < x1.length; ++i) {
        x1[i].data = p;
    }

    var t = e1.srcElement;
}
```

They are talking about `x1` which gets reassigned in this part of the code.
Altogether, I don't get, why they filled the array with `"abc"` on the first hand and second, I don't understand, why `x1` should now place the reassigend data at a different location (the IMG object location) in the heap than the previously assigned `"abc"` value.

Comment: Hey Lavair, welcome to the site! Replacing the images of code with properly formatted text will allow answerers to copy-paste the code directly, which is super helpful.

Comment: @Cowthulhu Hi, thanks for the tip. Gonna do it in a minute :)